# Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Dictionary<string>

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to write the interface for the request in my get route. Can you please help.
The interface should extend the default request interface but must include my id param.

See the error below:

```js
{
 "owner": "typescript",
 "code": "2430",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "Interface 'IGetCustomRequest<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'Request'.\n  Types of property 'params' are incompatible.\n    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Dictionary<string>'.",
 "source": "ts",
 "startLineNumber": 17,
 "startColumn": 11,
 "endLineNumber": 17,
 "endColumn": 28
}
```

```js
import express = require('express');

interface IGetParams {
    id: string
}


interface IGetCustomRequest<T> extends express.Request {
    params: T
}

var router = require('express').Router();

router.get("/:id", (req: IGetCustomRequest<IGetParams>, res: express.Response) => {

    console.log('sent', req.params)

    res.json(`${req.params.id} get params -----------------------`);
});

module.exports = router;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property [`params`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/3cd6ad7fa49791641e198f0b28592245b14cd825/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L457) in [`express.Request`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/3cd6ad7fa49791641e198f0b28592245b14cd825/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L205) type is restricted to a `Dictionary` type with string keys and values. Your `T` in `IGetCustomRequest` is not constrained, so the compiler complains that `Request` is incorrectly extended.

Have a look at the express types:

```
// copied from @types/express-serve-static-core

export interface Dictionary<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}

export type ParamsDictionary = Dictionary<string>;
export type ParamsArray = string[];
export type Params = ParamsDictionary | ParamsArray;

type Request<P extends Params = ParamsDictionary> = {
  params: P;
};
```

As a solution, you can restrict `T` in the form `<T extends ParamsDictionary>`:

```
interface IGetCustomRequest<T extends ParamsDictionary> extends Request {
  params: T;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEQWxgQiUygE8AeAFQD44BvAKDjgG0BrYSgLjgBnGFGQBzALoDaAbhYBfFi1CRYcGJTB4AChUwBbQYWKlyVOAF4CREmQo1hopGPpyV0eBq1xdUA4IBBKD9KSyERcQ4JN3APdU0dPUMw339jWzNQgB8fJMDgzEo5Fi88ACVgAEcAV2Bham04UFQkABNBXL9kq1TDdNN7RitWdjA8gW05eWLkVAwcPABJAHFgGF6OkcRWgUdxKaVZtCxcOBW1gGFq4Qh9Cpq6mDomkBb2zrSbAapGZuA2jr3WrCZhsOBjLqCaQHIA)